# Frame loss for above FullHD resolution .Is AVI Decompressor transform filter available in MediaFoundation?

Tags: c++, video, visual-c++, ms-media-foundation, mjpeg

I'm developing a multimedia streaming application for Desktop using SourceReader MediaFoundation technique.

I'm using USB camera device to show streaming. The camera supports 2-video formats: **YUY2 and MJPG**.

For 1980x1080p YUY2 video resolution, receiving only 48fps for 60fps. I fetched YUY2-RGB32 conversion from MSDN page and using in my application (**Note:** I didn't use any transform filter for color conversion).

For MJPG video format, I used **MJPEG Decoder MFT** to convert MJPG - YUY2 - RGB32 and then displaying on the window using Direct3D9. For specific resolution, I'm facing framerate drops from 60fps to 30fps(**Ex:** 1920x1080 60fps but drawing only 30-33fps).

Two ways, I verified in Graphedit to confirm about the filter:

1. Added **MJPEG Decompressor filter** and built the graph for MJPG video format to check fps for FullHD resolution and its showing 28fps for 60fps.
2. Added **AVI Decompressor filter** and built the graph for MJPG video format to check fps for FullHD resolution and its showing 60fps.

I have searched on many sites to find AVI decompressor for media foundation but no luck.

Anyone confirm, is there any filter available in MFT?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111362/media-foundation-mftransform-to-convert-mfsample-from-mjpg-to-yuy2-or-rgb24
However, on Windows 8 (and higher) I'd suggest using Video Processor MFT instead of Color Converter DSP to convert from YUY2 to RGB32. Video Processor MFT should be faster, because it uses the graphics hardware. Moreover, the Video Processor MFT should give you RGB32 IDirect3DSurface9 surfaces directly (wrapped in IMFMediaBuffer), if you configure it with IDirect3dDeviceManager9.

Comment: Is this a USB3 Camera? I don't think 1080p60 with YUY2 or MJPEG is possible with a USB2 camera. Have you verified you are getting the 60fps without any decoder? (NullRenderer or writing to avi)

Comment: Yes, its USB3 camera and supports 60fps for YUY2 and MJPEG. Without using any decoder, I can achieve 60fps. So there is no problem in my Device.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, VuVrit. I didn't configure IDirect3dDeviceManager9 in my application. Without configuring this, I'm receiving RGB32 frames and can achieve framerate 49 to 53fps for 1920x1080 YUY2 format but frames drawing very very slow. It's rendering like 4 to 5 fps on the window...Is it necessary to configure this interface to solve this rendering problem?if yes, can you guide me in a write to configure it.

Comment: Any idea, Vuvrit?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft ships [recent versions of] Windows with stock Motion JPEG decoders:

- [MJPEG Decompressor Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390691) for DirectShow
- MJPEG Decoder MFT for Media Foundation

To my best knowledge those do not share codebases, however both are not supposed to be performance efficient decoders.

Your using GraphEdit means you are trying DirectShow decoders and AVI Decompressor is supposedly using another (Video for Windows) codec which you did not identify.

For Media Foundation, you might be able to use Intel Hardware M-JPEG Decoder MFT or NVIDIA MJPEG Video Decoder MFT is you have respective hardware and drivers. Presumably, vendor specific decoders deliver better performance, and also have higher priority compared to generic software peers. Other than this, for an MFT form factor you might need to look at commercial decoders and/or custom developed, as the API itself is not so much popular to offer a wide range of options.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Roman...I used graph edit tool to verify the fps in DirectShow. I will enumerate Intel Hardware M-JPEG Decoder MFT  and use it in my application. Why frame drops occur for 1920x1080 YUY2 resolution? I'm using color conversion algorithm from this MSDN page:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd206750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. Could you please tell me the reason? Thank you once again.

Comment: You might be hitting different bottlenecks with different options. With MJPG video slow decoder is likely to be a bottleneck and you are expectedly get the symptoms described in the original question. If you capture YUY2, there is no decoding step but bandwidth might be a problem and a cause for capture frame rate reduction, as well as slower upload to video subsystem when it comes to presentation.